# How to get FB group by alias (FQL)

Tags: facebook-fql, alias, facebook-group

Does there exist any way to get group by it's alias (username)?

```
SELECT id, name, pic_big, type, url, username FROM profile WHERE username='somealias'
```

works for pages, but doesn't works for groups! For groups it returns

```
(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: somealias
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`profile` table is like a parent class for `user`, `group`, `page`, `event`, or `application` tables. (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile/)

It has field `username` but values in this field are filled from related tables, and table group has no field `username` (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group). So when we query profile using `where id = someid` we get such results:

```
SELECT id, name, pic_big, type, url, username FROM profile WHERE id= '195466193802264'
```

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 195466193802264, 
      "name": "Facebook Developers", 
      "pic_big": "https://www.facebook.com/images/litestand/bookmarks/sidebar/icons/groups/icon-default.png", 
      "type": "group", 
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/195466193802264/", 
      "username": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, username is empty for group.

**update**

After some investigation I found that groups CAN have usernames. Oficially they can't, but group's email part before @ symbol is it's username.

When you query the profile if you only specify its username you receive nothing. But if you'll add its name your group will appear.

Example:

```
SELECT id, name, pic_big, type, url, username FROM profile 
  WHERE username = 'rock.mfc' and type = 'group'
```

will result

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

But the query

```
SELECT id, name, pic_big, type, url, username FROM profile
  WHERE name = 'ROCK MUSIC FANS CLUB' and username = 'rock.mfc' and type = 'group'
```

will give the required result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 268045023346892, 
      "name": "ROCK MUSIC FANS CLUB", 
      "pic_big": "https://www.facebook.com/images/litestand/bookmarks/sidebar/icons/groups/icon-guitar.png", 
      "type": "group", 
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/rock.mfc/", 
      "username": "rock.mfc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: So, it is impossible to get group by alias?
Where I can find connection between group id and it alias?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group - there are the fileds that entity `group` has. So you can use `name` - full name of group (in example it's "Facebook Developers") or ID

Comment: I know that, it means that my task impossible? Yes/No? :)
Name is not unique unlike username.

Comment: well username field in table user is deprecated now and no longer supported (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user). And group table has no username field at all. So yes, I think that your task is impossible (and even if possible you'll have to switch off username bc its deprecated). The best thing to use is ID of user/group/etc, it is definitely unique.

Comment: So, how I can get id of group if I have only it username?  
For example - https://www.facebook.com/groups/rock.mfc/ - how can I do something with that group via API? Where I can get its id? :)  
Its very strange situation, aren't?

Comment: I investigated this issue further - seem that Facebook documentation sometimes does not coincide with real state :) So I'll update the answer now with my investigation and seem that you CAN query the group having it's username. The only other thing you need is it's name.

Comment: It looks like mysticism!)) Very thanks, bro, you done really useful work, big thanks and respect! :)  

PS: Maybe you try help me with another task? ;)  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226157/how-to-get-users-posts-count